# Flutter workmanager with BLOC and repository pattern

Tags: flutter, bloc, android-workmanager

I use [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) and with `repository pattern`. There was a need to execute the code in the background according to the schedule, for this I use [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) The problem is that the `workmanager` is executed in a separate method, which is initialized outside the `main` method, and it does not know anything about the context or the code below like `MyApp`

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) {
    
    //How i can access bloc or repository from here?
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() async {

Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask('uniqueName', 'taskName',
      constraints: Constraints(
        networkType: NetworkType.connected,
        requiresBatteryNotLow: true,
      ),
      frequency: const Duration(minutes: 5));


}
```

`Workmanager` is initialized at the very beginning of the `main` method and before  `runApp MyApp`, it has no context, and my repository and bloc have not even been created yet. I can’t figure out how to access the bloc from the workmanager.